# iPhone battery symbol is red, doesn't acknowledge charging, but is apparently charged

Tags: battery, iphone, charging

I have an iPhone 3G,

1. When I plug in the charger,  the big red battery on the locked screen is red, low and doesn't appear to be charging. When I unlock the screen, the small battery symbol on the upper right is green with a bolt.
2. When I unplug it, the battery symbol in the upper right is low and red, but the phone seems to be charged.
3. The phone syncs to my computer fine when connected.

Does anyone know what the problem is and if it can be fixed? Is it relatively benign, or perhaps an early sign that it is reaching its final stage of life?

**Update**

Although I am still no closer to the answer, and I had tried powering off manually, I let the battery run out (about 7 days at 1hr/day, no cell phone service) and when I charged it again, the issue resolved.

Comment: Have you seen how long it will go without being charged before it dies?

Comment: I am doing it now - it has been about three days, using it about 1 hr / day, without any phone use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it happens when you put your iPhone for charging more time.

Please power-off and restart your iPhone. Mostly this solves problem.

Comment: I've already tried this; I've also restored the default settings, but it didn't work.

Comment: as in my update, allowing the battery to run out and charging again fixed, although powering off did not. Thanks for your help.